# Loading JavaScript file in WordPress using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to load my own JavaScript file using `wp_enqueue_script` function but it won't work. I have stored this in `functions.php`. Any Suggestions?

```
<?php
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, either on the client or server side?

Comment: There's no errors on both client or server side, no script tags appear on console. I've been on this for hours :(

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are two likely reasons that you're not seeing the script getting embedded...

Scenario 1: You are already using the handle "test" somewhere else in the theme/plugins. This will result in only the first call to `wp_enqueue_script( 'test', ... )` being enqueued. If using a duplicate handle, the latter call is ignored. Either make sure there are no other handles called "test" or use something clearly unique.

Scenario 2: Your theme is missing `wp_head()` and/or `wp_footer()`. This will result in the script getting enqueued but not having a function called to display the items, including yours, enqueued. You should verify that in your theme or the parent theme, whichever one has your header.php file, that you include the `wp_head()` just before the closing `<head>` tag.